# can default model binder generate IEnumerable<FormItem>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

server:

```
public class FormItems
{
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> Values { get; set; }
}
```

client:

```
<form id="myform" action="/" method="post">
    <!-- Those inputs could be added dynamically -->
    <input type="text" name="[0].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="[1].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="[2].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="[3].Value" />

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

and finally AJAXify the form:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I use default model binder get the ajax data into strongly typed IEnumerable?

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(FormItems data)
```

Comment: It all depends on how exactly you have it structured in the View. Can you post the HTML from your View?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `MyClass` is something like this

```
public class MyClass
{
     public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Your html should look like this (note that name of each value input is prefixed by matching enumerable property name in `FormItems`)

```
< form id="myform" action="/" method="post">
    <!-- Those inputs could be added dynamically -->
    <input type="text" name="Values[0].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="Values[1].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="Values[2].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="Values[3].Value" />

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```